# Proper Logging for Eclipse plug-in development

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, error-handling, eclipse-plugin

When I am catching an exception that I have thrown, what is the proper logging of that exception? I know the user can see the "error log" view in eclipse.

Here are a couple different ways that I can log... Not sure which is the best and what exactly the user will see when I log it this way.

1. Simply print the stack trace. Will this show in the "error log" view?
2. `Activator.getDefault().log(e.getMessage(), e);` In each catch clause, 
      I can log the information with the Activator that is associated with
      the plug-ins ID.

Are there betters way to log the error in eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Printing the stack trace will not go in the error log, it will just be lost (except when running from within Eclipse or with a console).

The `Activator` based logging is the usual way to log. The code logging provided by the `Plugin` or `AbstractUIPlugin` class is:

```
ILog log = Activator.getDefault().getLog();

log.log(new Status(....));
```

`Status` has a number of different constructors depending on exactly what you want to log. For example:

```
new Status(IStatus.ERROR, ID, errorNumber, message, exception);

new Status(IStatus.ERROR, message, exception);
```

`Activator` is the class defined as the plug-in activator in the `Bundle-Activator` in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF.

If the plug-in does not have an activator you can get get the `ILog` using:

```
ILog log = Platform.getLog(getClass());
```

or

```
ILog log = Platform.getLog(bundle);
```

where `bundle` is the `Bundle` for the plug-in.

Comment: Cool. Thanks Greg! And the Activator based logging will go into the error log?

Comment: Yes that logging goes in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: What `Activator` class is this? From what package and plugin? I think I have tried them all but not found any with a `getDefault` and a `getLog` method.

Comment: @Lii If you let Eclipse create the Activator for you when you create a plugin and specify 'plug-in makes contributions to the UI' then the Activator that is created has `getDefault()` and extends `AbstractUIPlugin`.

Comment: Perhaps this information is obsolete as of 2019-12, but I'm trying to do this, and the comment from @Lii is relevant, and I don't understand your answer. When I try to insert that call to "Activator.getDefault()" and then add the import, none of the FQCN choices have a "getDefault()" method.

Comment: The activator class is an _optional_ yet idiomatic class to manage a plugin's lifecycle. There is at most one activator per plug-in. You can create it by hand but Eclipse IDE also proposes to generate one at plug-in creation. The activator class is usually called `Activator` but that's just a convention. The actual path to the class is stored in MANIFEST.MF (`Bundle-Activator` key). The static `getDefault()` method returns the actual object representing the plugin and which is given to the activator through the `start` method (available if the activator extends `AbstractUIPlugin` or `Plugin`).